# Change WordPress post-state in Admin Area

Tags: posts, pages

Im wondering if it's possible to add custom post state's to other pages?
Like *Frontpage* and *Blog*

I mean the black text: --Voorpagina (*Frontpage*)
 
[image: Post State WordPresss]

I have tried this in functions.php.

```
add_filter('display_post_states', 'wpsites_custom_post_states');

function wpsites_custom_post_states($states) { 
    global $post; 
    if( ('page' == get_post_type($post->ID) ) 
        && ( '/themes/Lef-en-Liefde/woningoverzicht.php' == get_page_templ‌​ate_slug( $post->ID ) ) ) {

            $states[] = __('Custom state'); 

    } 
}
```

But then the original post states (frontpage and blog) are gone.

Thanks in advance,

Gino

Comment: What research have you done and what code have you tried?

Comment: May you please elaborate your question? As @AndyMacaulay-Brook stated, what have you tried so far? This way we can help understand your situation.

Comment: I have tried this in functions.php. <?php
add_filter('display_post_states', 'wpsites_custom_post_states');
function wpsites_custom_post_states($states) {
    global $post;
    if( ('page'==get_post_type($post->ID)) && ('/themes/Lef-en-Liefde/woningoverzicht.php'==get_page_template_slug($post->ID)) ) {
        $states[] = __('Custom state');
    }
} 

But then the original post states (frontpage and blog) are gone.

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't return a value, so you are effectively wiping the existing states.

Also, this hook passes you the current post as an object, so you can use that instead of the global $post.

Additionally `get_page_templ‌​ate_slug` returns a path that is relative to your theme's root, so if your theme directory is called `Lef-en-Liefde` and the template file placed at the top level of that directory is called `woningoverzicht.php`, then your condition `'/themes/Lef-en-Liefde/woningoverzicht.php' == get_page_templ‌​ate_slug($post->ID)` can never be true.

So, correcting/changing for those points, this should work:

```
add_filter('display_post_states', 'wpse240081_custom_post_states',10,2);

function wpse240081_custom_post_states( $states, $post ) { 
    
    if ( ( 'page' == get_post_type( $post->ID ) ) 
        && ( 'woningoverzicht.php' == get_page_templ‌​ate_slug( $post->ID ) ) ) {

            $states[] = __('Custom state'); 

    } 

    return $states;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to add priority and arg number params to the `add_filter` call for this to work. See an example below in @roland-soos comment.

Comment: @certainlyakey yes, good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how WooCommerce does it:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'add_display_post_states', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add a post display state for special WC pages in the page list table.
 *
 * @param array   $post_states An array of post display states.
 * @param WP_Post $post        The current post object.
 */
function add_display_post_states( $post_states, $post ) {
    if ( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['wc_page_for_shop'] = __( 'Shop Page', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    if ( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['wc_page_for_cart'] = __( 'Cart Page', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    if ( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['wc_page_for_checkout'] = __( 'Checkout Page', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    if ( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['wc_page_for_myaccount'] = __( 'My Account Page', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    if ( wc_get_page_id( 'terms' ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['wc_page_for_terms'] = __( 'Terms and Conditions Page', 'woocommerce' );
    }

    return $post_states;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use that filter in custom plugin, you will need to use the function "get_post_meta" because the function "get_page_templ‌​ate_slug" is not already loaded

exemple:

```
add_filter('display_post_states', 'wpse240081_custom_post_states', 10, 2);

function wpse240081_custom_post_states( $states, $post ) {
    
    // if is list page and name template file php...
    if ( ( 'page' == get_post_type( $post->ID ) ) && ( 'your-template-name.php' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) ) {

        $states[] = __('Custom state');
    }

    return $states;
}
```