# Creating/editing custom 'post-state'

Tags: post-status

I want to be able to easily create/edit my own custom "post-state" for display in the Pages back end.

I *only* want this text appearing after the page name - not in the status dropdown, or anywhere else.

WooCommerce, Elementor & a whole host of other plugins do this for their own internally created pages, to the point where they even concatenate if there is an pre-existing state eg:
[image: post-state example]
However, I cannot seem to find anywhere that I can just easily edit this text, or add my own.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240081/change-wordpress-post-state-in-admin-area) was the only one I could find that asks about `post-state` and the provided answers, while they might work, rely on my editing functions.php and dealing with code every time I want to add/change the text or even if the page id changes.

I would prefer something more simple: an "edit post state" button for each page in the list that just brings a text box that I can input new or change existing text for any page I want.

Unsuccessful so far in searching the plugins at wordpress.org (only results are for highlighting WP built-in states such as 'draft', adding in preset states such as 'archive', or creating entire new `Post Status` that appears in the dropdown & other places.)

If there is another type of plugin/code that can provide the same functionality, that would also be acceptable - basically I want to be able to just add a short admin-only description for the sake of differentiating between nondescript page names*, without having to change the actual page name itself.

**such as when I am experimenting with a few different plugins that generate the same page names eg. `My Account`, or if I want a sandbox page but still have it called the same name as my proper page.*

Comment: One of my biggest issues when searching for a resolution to this question was finding out what that grey text is actually referred to!! I had to resort to looking at source code for a clue in the html & it is called `post-state` in there, also when attempting to tag I did not see the `post-status` tag that @fuxia just added for me - thanks, this might speed up discovering a good solution.

Comment: Upon further delving there appears to be a plugin called [Edit Flow](http://editflow.org/) but that seems like a lot of bulk just to do this one small thing

Answer (score 1):

_post_states( WP_Post $post )

Parameters #Parameters

$post
(WP_Post) (Required)

[Code Reference from wordpress.org (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_post_states/)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_post_states/)

```
function _post_states($post) {
$post_states = array();
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_status'] ) )
    $post_status = $_REQUEST['post_status'];
else
    $post_status = '';

if ( !empty($post->post_password) )
    $post_states['protected'] = __('Password protected');
if ( 'private' == $post->post_status && 'private' != $post_status )
    $post_states['private'] = __('Private');
if ( 'draft' === $post->post_status ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customize_changeset_uuid', true ) ) {
        $post_states[] = __( 'Customization Draft' );
    } elseif ( 'draft' !== $post_status ) {
        $post_states['draft'] = __( 'Draft' );
    }
} elseif ( 'trash' === $post->post_status && get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customize_changeset_uuid', true ) ) {
    $post_states[] = __( 'Customization Draft' );
}
if ( 'pending' == $post->post_status && 'pending' != $post_status )
    $post_states['pending'] = _x('Pending', 'post status');
if ( is_sticky($post->ID) )
    $post_states['sticky'] = __('Sticky');

if ( 'future' === $post->post_status ) {
    $post_states['scheduled'] = __( 'Scheduled' );
}

if ( 'page' === get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
    if ( intval( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['page_on_front'] = __( 'Front Page' );
    }

    if ( intval( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) === $post->ID ) {
        $post_states['page_for_posts'] = __( 'Posts Page' );
    }
}

if ( intval( get_option( 'wp_page_for_privacy_policy' ) ) === $post->ID ) {
    $post_states['page_for_privacy_policy'] = __( 'Privacy Policy Page' );
}

/**
 * Filters the default post display states used in the posts list table.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 * @since 3.6.0 Added the `$post` parameter.
 *
 * @param array   $post_states An array of post display states.
 * @param WP_Post $post        The current post object.
 */
$post_states = apply_filters( 'display_post_states', $post_states, $post );

if ( ! empty($post_states) ) {
    $state_count = count($post_states);
    $i = 0;
    echo ' &mdash; ';
    foreach ( $post_states as $state ) {
        ++$i;
        ( $i == $state_count ) ? $sep = '' : $sep = ', ';
        echo "<span class='post-state'>$state$sep</span>";
    }
}
```

---

[image]

> For Example: This Code from ***Ultimate Member*** plugin

```
/**
     * Add a post display state for special UM pages in the page list table.
     *
     * @param array $post_states An array of post display states.
     * @param \WP_Post $post The current post object.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function add_display_post_states( $post_states, $post ) {

        foreach ( UM()->config()->core_pages as $page_key => $page_value ) {
            $page_id = UM()->options()->get( UM()->options()->get_core_page_id( $page_key ) );

            if ( $page_id == $post->ID ) {
                $post_states[ 'um_core_page_' . $page_key ] = sprintf( 'UM %s', $page_value['title'] );
            }
        }

        return $post_states;
    }
```